# How do you find the maximum value of $r$ in a polar function?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I have $\, r=\cos\alpha +\sin2\alpha,\quad 0\le\alpha\le\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Do you then find $\dfrac{dr}{d\alpha}$ and let that $=0$ ?

I am after just a few set of instructions.

Comment: You first look for a points where derivative is $0$, and then find second derivative. If it's positive, then that point is local minimum, if negative - maximum, if $0$, then it's inflection point. Since you have endpoints, check also values at those. At the very end compare all values you found and decide which is the point, or the value.

Comment: @Kaster: You could write that as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the first derivative of $r$ vs. $\alpha$ you find:
$$\frac{dr}{d\alpha}=-\sin(\alpha)+2\cos(2\alpha)$$
putting this to zero, you find:
$$\alpha=.6348668713, 2.506725783, -1.002966954, -2.138625700$$
Take the second derivative of $r$ which is:
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\alpha^2}-\cos(\alpha)-4\sin(2\alpha)$$
in these points. If it's negative, this give you a maximum

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @Riccardo : why would one want to put the *second* derivative equal to zero? We're trying to find extrema points of the function, not of its first derivative...

Comment: @DonAntonio: it' true. I confused the first derivative with the second. You have to see only if in the points in wich the first derivative is zero, the second derivative is greather than zero or less than zero.

Comment: I thought so, @Riccardo . Try to edit your post and correct it.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Just done

Answer (score 1):

We have to investigate
$$r(\alpha):=\cos\alpha+\sin(2\alpha)\qquad(0\leq\alpha\leq{\pi\over2})\ .$$
We note in passing that $r(0)=1$, $\ r({\pi\over2})=0$ and compute
$$r'(\alpha)=-\sin\alpha +2\cos(2\alpha)=-(4u^2+u-2)\ ,$$
where we have put $\sin\alpha=:u$. Solving $r'(\alpha)=0$ gives
$$u_\pm={-1\pm\sqrt{33}\over 8}\ ,$$
and since a usable $u$ has to lie in the interval $[0,1]$ we are left with
$$\sin\alpha_0=u_+={\sqrt{33}-1\over 8}\doteq0.593\ ,$$
which leads to $$\cos\alpha_0=\sqrt{1-u_+^2}={\sqrt{30+2\sqrt{33}}\over8}\ .$$
In this way we obtain
$$r(\alpha_0)=\cos\alpha_0(1+2\sin\alpha_0)={\sqrt{30+2\sqrt{33}}\over8}{\sqrt{33}+3\over 4}\doteq1.760\ .$$
Since $r(\alpha_0)$ is greater than both $r(0)$ and $r({\pi\over2})$ it follows that the obtained value $r(\alpha_0)\doteq1.760$ is the maximal value for $r$ in the given interval.

It is not necessary to compute second derivatives here: The extreme values of $r$ are among $r(0)$, $\>r({\pi\over2})$, and the values of $r$ at the zeros of $r'$ in the interval $\ \bigl]0,{\pi\over2}\bigr[\ $.

[image]